# How to delete rows from delta historical files on databricks?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, vacuum

I have some historic tables that need deletion on some rows because we no longer can have that data.
I also need to delete this data from previous delta table versions because of audit purposes.

For what I've read the VACUUM command would be good for my use case, with a small retention period of 5 hours.
I'm testing this and the history won't go away with VACUUM, neither the VACUUM operation gets logged on the table history.

Steps:

1. Delete the rows from the table.

```
DELETE FROM delta.`path_to_table` WHERE code = 20
```

2. Vacuum the delta table.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")

QUERY = f"""VACUUM delta.`path_to_table` RETAIN 5 HOURS"""

result = spark.sql(QUERY)
```

3. Check history of delta table.

History of the table is the same without any VACUUM operation.

Any idea about this behaviour? Any suggestions of what I should try?

Thank you.

Comment: If you run the vacuum 5 hours after the delete, then the data should be removed. The history delta log is retained longer (default 30 days if i remember).

Comment: Note, VACUUM was not reported in the history until 2.3.0 https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/tag/v2.3.0

Comment: @ferdyh do you have a source for that information?
I will try a test with 5 hours gap, but right now after I vacuum I still can query older versions and the deleted data is there.

Comment: "If you run VACUUM on a Delta table, you lose the ability to time travel back to a version older than the specified data retention period." Source: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-vacuum.html#vacuum-a-delta-table